# Taking turmeric bulbs from Asia to Europe

Tags: luggage, borders

My Asian sister-in-law was given turmeric bulbs by her mother. She is flying to the Schengen space via Taipei and then Amsterdam.

Will those products be allowed in by EC laws?

Comment: Most likely illegal. Live plants often carry pathogens which may cause great harm in other countries.

Answer (score 2):

That's unlikely - not without some effort for extra documentation. Any plants being brought in have to be declared, and you need certifications with them: https://ec.europa.eu/food/plant/plant_health_biosecurity/non_eu_trade_en

> certain plants, plant products and other objects (listed in Part B, Annex V - Directive 
>   2000/29/EC) entering the EU must have a phytosanitary certificate
>   guaranteeing that they are:
>
> - properly inspected;
> - free from quarantine harmful organisms and practically free from other harmful organisms;
> - in line with the plant health regulations of the importing country.
>
> The exporting country's national plant protection authorities issue
>   the certificates. Once in the EU, a plant passport may replace the
>   phytosanitary certificate for imported plants, plant products and
>   other objects which are also listed in Part A of Annex V.

There are some exceptions, but it's a LOT of legalese to wade through. Point is, you will be asked about it and the onus will be on you to provide evidence that it's "safe" to be allowed in to the country.